# Why is python not recognizing my input

Tags: python

So I'm writing a program for that is supposed to take input of either 1 or 2 from a user, and add the inputs to the total until the total has reached 21. I have a while statement that makes sure the input is either a 1 or 2 but when I test it no matter what input I enter it shows that 1 and 2 are answers that don't qualify. So I don't know if I wrote the parameters for my while statement incorrectly or if my input is not being recognized correctly.

[image]

If someone could tell me how I can make my code continue running if 1 or 2 is inputed that'd be much appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: I cannot see your code

Comment: oh please paste your code in plain text

Comment: It is bad to post code or data as pictures.  There is no way to copy and paste a picture into a code editor. So it will be much harder, and thus less likely, for someone to help. To get the most out of the site it is important to [ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), that includes creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that the input from raw_input() will be a string, so when comparing, use:

```
increase != "1"
```

Also I think that you are looking for this actually:

```
increase != "1" and increase != "2"
```

Notice that I've changed the **or** by an **and**

To use int as input, you can do something like:

```
int(raw_input("Insert number here"))
```

Comment: Oh ok, thank you so much.

Comment: please @AS.Alhaj mark as solved is this suit you

Answer (score 0):

As user1532587 explained: You were comparing a string to an integer. That's it.
However, using raw_input() is the right way. I wouldn't recommend using input() in Python 2.x .

Keep also in mind, that there is actually no need to use a print statement and a raw_input statement, you could easily combine them:

```
increase = raw_input("player 1: blabla while the total is {}".format(current))
```

.format(current) is just - in my opinion - a better habit than ""%current

Btw, a common way to handle input is using *try* and *except*,
so all in all, it could look like this:

```
def play_twentyone():

    current = 0

    while current < 21:

        increase = raw_input("player1: blabla the total is {}\n".format(current))

        while True:

            try:
                if int(increase) in [1,2]: break 
            except ValueError: #handling the error which could occur, e.g int("five")
                pass

            increase = raw_input("Invalid input, please try again\n")

        current += int(increase)
```

Or a simple way using strings, not integers:

```
def play_twentyone():

    current = 0

    while current < 21:

        increase = raw_input("player1: blabla the total is {}\n".format(current))

        while increase not in ("1","2"):
            increase = raw_input("Invalid input, please try again\n")

        current += int(increase)
```

note:

```
increase not in "12"
```

would also accept an empty string/input-->not ok